# Customized width and height in DOMPDF

Tags: php, dompdf

Is there anyway i can set the generated PDF's width and height? i want to customized the width and height of the PDF. Normally it would be on a size of a short bond paper but how can i customized it? lets say for example i want it to be 200 x 500 pixel in size?

Any idea would be very much appreciated! cheers!

Comment: as DOMPDF is very slow, I'd advise you to try a better and much faster alternative like [wkhtmltopdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)

Comment: on the current system we are developing, we are using DOMPDF so i have to fit in. thank for the suggestion though ill keep in mind this one

Answer (score 9):

You can set your own format, without having to change DOMPDF code, by passing an array when you're calling DOMPDF::set_paper(). Make sure it contains the width and the height in points, like this:

`$dompdf->set_paper(array(0, 0, 595, 841), 'portrait');`

Comment: Do you know what the first 2 values in the array are?

Comment: I'm not sure why they did it this way, but the 4 values together are used to calculate width and height.
Like this: `$width = $size[2] - $size[0]` and `$height = $size[3] - $size[1]`. So it's easiest to just let the first 2 values be 0. That's also the way they did it with all the predefined page formats.

Comment: This is a common format when drawing a rectangle: `[x1,y1, x2,y2]`. As Michiel said, you should keep the first two values as zero: `0,0`

Comment: i get it works but how to make it in cm instead of pixel?

Comment: Convert pixel in to cm and use in css like: @page { size: 10cm 10cm; }

Answer (score 3):

DOMPDF handles the paper size via the configuration.

```
define ("DOMPDF_DEFAULT_PAPER_SIZE", "letter");
```

You can referrer to all available sizes there:

https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/2eaf8fe0f1c95ab76e7a428a39a54dd240e2b2ec/src/Adapter/CPDF.php#L40

Comment: what if i want to customized it size? i there a way?

Comment: Simply add it to the list: `CPDF_Adapter::$PAPER_SIZES['mysize'] = array(0, 0, …, …);`

Comment: It did work. thank yyou so much.. but when i tried to make it more smaller, the text grows bigger. how can i set the text size? ^^

Comment: Is the width/height of the generated PDF correct according to your paper size?

Comment: i really dont know about it. what's important is that the size changes so ill be fixing some of these later. thank you greut!