# How to set custom width and height of pdf using dompdf?

Tags: php, dompdf

When I create my pdf using dompdf it generates it as default width and height. I want to set custom width and height of my created pdf. If it is not possible in dompdf then kindly suggest some other plugin for php.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835323/customized-width-and-height-in-dompdf

Answer (score 42, accepted):

By default it's going to render on 'US Letter', you can change this by using:

```
$dompdf->setPaper(DEFAULT_PDF_PAPER_SIZE, 'portrait');
```

You can use 'letter', 'legal', 'A4', etc..

Nevertheless you can set your own size like this:

```
$customPaper = array(0,0,360,360);
$dompdf->setPaper($customPaper);
```

More info: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage

Comment: With dompdf 0.6 you can also use the CSS `@page` rule to set your page size/orientation. e.g. `@page { size: a4 landscape; }` or `@page { size: 360pt 360pt; }`.

Comment: You can see the full list of supported named sizes in the [CPDF Adapter source](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/v0.6.1/include/cpdf_adapter.cls.php#L37).

Comment: Glad to be of service.

Comment: looks like "set_paper" is now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for how to make the height of the document dynamic to print on rolls of thermal paper. This was the closest I got to a solution using DomPDF.

- You need creating the file with all the properties and loading the html:

  ```
   $pdf = new Dompdf();

   $options = $pdf->getOptions();
   $pdf->set_paper(array(0, 0, 164.44, 842.07), 'portrait');

   $options->set(array(
       'isRemoteEnabled' => true,
       'isHtml5ParserEnabled' => true
   ));
   $pdf->setOptions($options);

   $pdf->loadHtml($template);
  ```
- Before rendering, define a callback function, and, in the global array define a variable where the height will be stored, after that, make the render and unset the pdf object, now you have the body height of your file plus 100 px.

  ```
   /*
   * Workaround to get the body height
   */
   $GLOBALS['bodyHeight'] = 0;

   $pdf->setCallbacks([
       'myCallbacks' => [
           'event' => 'end_frame', 
           'f' => function ($frame) {
               $node = $frame->get_node();

               if (strtolower($node->nodeName) === "body") {
                   $padding_box = $frame->get_padding_box();
                   $GLOBALS['bodyHeight'] += $padding_box['h'];
               }
           }
       ]
   ]);

   $pdf->render();
   unset($pdf);
   $docHeight = $GLOBALS['bodyHeight'] + 100;
  ```
- Now you need create again your file, but now you have the height that you need define to your pdf file.

  ```
   $pdf = new Dompdf();
   $options = $pdf->getOptions();

   $pdf->setPaper([0,0,227, $docHeight]);
  ```

Source:
[Create a single page PDF file with auto height](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1524#issuecomment-326137908)