# Is there any way to set fixed height and dynamic height to a html page which will then be converted into a pdf?

Tags: laravel, dompdf

I am using laravel php framework to generate restaurant bills and print these bills using a thermal printer. Bills are created using dompdf. This pdf should have a fixed width and dynamic height. How should i achieve this?

Comment: you can create custom sizes in dompdf and im sure there are plenty of resources that show you how

Comment: Check this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25376901/how-to-set-custom-width-and-height-of-pdf-using-dompdf

Comment: You missed the point @user3532758 He wanted to make pdfs with dynamic height not setting a custom height