# I got eror in pdf view with table rowspan

Tags: laravel, pdf

the rowspan is not working after the table change to new page in pdf
im using laravel-dompdf for pdf

[table view in pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYcbt.png)

my table code

```
<table class="table-sm text-center align-middle">

        <tr>

            <th rowspan="2">NAMA PASANGAN CALON</th>
            <th colspan="15">Rincian Perolehan Suara</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Jumlah <br> Tiap <br> Baris</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Jumlah</th>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            @for ($i = 1; $i <= 15; $i++)
                <td>{{ $i }}</td>
            @endfor
        </tr>
        @for ($c = 0; $c < 3; $c++)
            @for ($i = 1; $i <= 11; $i++)
                <tr>
                    @if ($i === 1)
                        <td rowspan="11">asdkjhasdkjhasdkjhasdjhsjahd and asdjaksdkasdkjkasdjh</td>
                    @endif
                    @for ($j = 1; $j <= 15; $j++)
                        <td>{{ str_repeat('|', 5) }}</td>
                    @endfor
                    <td>{{ 5 * 15 }}</td>
                    @if ($i === 1)
                        <td class="align-top" rowspan="11">{{ 5 * 15 * 11 }}</td>
                    @endif
                </tr>
            @endfor
        @endfor



    </table>
```

i hope the reult of the table is like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJRzx.png)

Answer (score 0):

2 solution, make your content smaller or make your paper size bigger

this references will help you = [How to set custom width and height of pdf using dompdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25376901/how-to-set-custom-width-and-height-of-pdf-using-dompdf)

```
//add this
$customPaper = array(0,0,360,360);
$dompdf->setPaper($customPaper);
```

set your custom resolution/paper size by your own. try it by yourself for what size you needed. that's answer is only sample.

or maybe this will help you

```
border-spacing: -1px;
```

here for reference = https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1284